# How to test https rest webservice in postman

Tags: web-services, rest, ssl, https, self-signed

I have deployed the a rest webservice over https using self signed certificate. Now i am facing the issue in postman while trying to test it. Error is same as follows:-[image]

I also follow the post from this link [using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/) but i am not able to find the connection tab as mentioned in the step 3.

Can anybody please help me how can i resolve that certificate issue.

Thanks

Comment: Which browser you are using to get the certificate? and are you getting the SSL not trusted error on that browser while hitting your https endpoint?

Comment: @Lijin I am using chrome browser and yes it's showing not secure as certificate is self-signed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Try open the same URL in your chrome browser.  You may get privacy
  error.  Click advanced link and proceed.  Come back to postman and
  send your request.

Answer (score 2):

In Postman go menu File/Settings in General tab disable "*SSL certificate verification*".